# Group/Control template options

Tags: 2013, display-template, web

We have made our own control and item templates for use with the content search web parts. One of our item templates shows "cards" for each returned item.

Currently we have one control template for when we want one column of cards, another control template when we want two columns, another when we want three columns. And then if we have a change or QA we need to go in and fix three different control templates.

I would love to be able to have one template and have the user/designer be able to edit the control template properties in the UI and set the number of columns.

Is there anyway to add properties into the control templates?

Comment: How do you decide which control template to choose for an item?

Comment: You can't choose a different group/control template for an individual item. But you can edit a webpart (for example content search web part) and specify which template to use.